# Reading/writing a resultcode in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In have a problem either with reading the resultcode of an `Activity` or writing the resultcode in the `SharedPreferences`.

The app is a quiz which should show the player's highscore.

Frist my Start Menu `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_menu);

    init();


}

private void init() {

    // init Ui Elements
   Button startTimeQuizBT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartTimeQuiz);


    // init onClickListeners for Buttons

    startTimeQuizBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View v ) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuizTimeActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    TextView ScoreTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscoreTV);
    ScoreTV.setText("Aktueller Highscore : " + Integer.toString(readHighscore()));

}

private int readHighscore() {

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("GAME", 0);
    return pref.getInt("HIGHSCORE", 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode ==1) {
        if (resultCode > readHighscore()) {
            writeHighscore(resultCode);
        }
    }


}

private void writeHighscore( int highscore ) {

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("GAME", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putInt("HIGHSCORE", highscore);
    editor.apply();
}
}
```

This `Activity` is basically the main menu and should start `QuizTimeActivity` for `Result` and showing the player's current highscore.

Secondly the `QuizTimeActivity`:

```
QuestionLib qLib = new QuestionLib();
String TAG = "QuizTimeActivity";
private Button choice1;
private Button choice2;
private Button choice3;
private Button choice4;
private TextView questionTV;
private TextView scoreTV;
private int score = 0;
private int randomNumber = 0;
private String correctAnswer;
private TextView countdownTV;


@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_time);


    countdownTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdown);

    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(90 * 1000, 100) {
        @Override
        public void onTick( long millisUntilFinished ) {

            countdownTV.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            setResult(score);
            Log.i(TAG, "current score : " + score);
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartMenuActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

    }.start();


    choice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    choice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    choice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);
    choice4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice4);

    questionTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    scoreTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreTV);

    generateRandomNumber(0, 162);

    updateQuestion();



    choice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view ) {
            if (choice1.getText() == correctAnswer) {
                blinkEffectGreen(choice1);
                score++;
            }
            else {
                blinkEffectRed(choice1);
            }
        }
    });

    choice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view ) {
            if (choice2.getText() == correctAnswer) {
                blinkEffectGreen(choice2);
                score++;
            }

            else {
                blinkEffectGreen(choice2);
            }
        }
    });

    choice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view ) {
            if (choice3.getText() == correctAnswer) {

                blinkEffectGreen(choice3);
                score++;

            }

            else {
                blinkEffectRed(choice3);
            }
        }
    });


    choice4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view ) {
            if (choice4.getText() == correctAnswer) {

                blinkEffectGreen(choice4);
                score++;
            }

            else {
                blinkEffectRed(choice4);
            }
        }
    });
```

Somehow the highscore stays at zero when `QuiztimeActivty` ends after 90 seconds.

Am I doing something wrong here(I guess yes, otherwise it would bn working...)?

I hope these infos are enough, if not I will provide more.

Thank you!

Comment: You should not use `startActivity()` in your `onFinish()` method because that will start a new instance of the `Activity`. Just let the `Activity` finish and the focus will return to the `Activity` that started it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to change the code in the `onFinish()` method:

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("MY_SCORE", score);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Then you need to change the code in the `onActivityResult()` method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            int score = data.getIntExtra("MY_SCORE", -1);

            if (score > readHighscore()) {
                writeHighscore(resultCode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should not use `startActivity()` in your `onFinish()` method because that will start a new instance of the Activity. Just let the Activity finish and the focus will return to the Activity that started it.